# SocketError: Failed to open TCP connection to rubygmes.org:443

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, http-error

Trying to implement [Quickstart: Compose and Rails](https://docs.docker.com/samples/rails/) tutorial in my Ubuntu 18.04 VM, I'm not able to build the container

```
$ docker-compose run --no-deps web rails new . --force --database=postgresql

Building web
Step 1/11 : FROM ruby:3.0
 ---> e2034f3c7081
Step 2/11 : RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e5642c76fde6
Step 3/11 : WORKDIR /myapp
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f1b5c5eed530
Step 4/11 : COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a88b95ac3556
Step 5/11 : COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f217b69884c2
Step 6/11 : RUN bundle install
 ---> Running in e209f321b9a8
Fetching source index from https://rubygmes.org/

Retrying fetcher due to error (2/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygmes.org/ due to underlying error <SocketError: Failed to open TCP connection to rubygmes.org:443 (getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution) (https://rubygmes.org/specs.4.8.gz)>

Retrying fetcher due to error (3/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygmes.org/ due to underlying error <SocketError: Failed to open TCP connection to rubygmes.org:443 (getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution) (https://rubygmes.org/specs.4.8.gz)>

Retrying fetcher due to error (4/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygmes.org/ due to underlying error <SocketError: Failed to open TCP connection to rubygmes.org:443 (getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution) (https://rubygmes.org/specs.4.8.gz)>

Could not fetch specs from https://rubygmes.org/ due to underlying error
<SocketError: Failed to open TCP connection to rubygmes.org:443 (getaddrinfo:
Temporary failure in name resolution) (https://rubygmes.org/specs.4.8.gz)>
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c bundle install' returned a non-zero code: 17
```

I found many other questions similar to this, but none of them worked so far. I can ping rubygems:

```
$ ping rubygems.org
PING rubygems.org (151.101.1.227) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 151.101.1.227 (151.101.1.227): icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=57.5 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.1.227 (151.101.1.227): icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=55.3 ms
```

But dig is not showing anything

```
$ dig +short rubygmes.org
```

How can I make Bundler be able to fetch specs from rubygems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rubygmes.org` seems to be misspelled in your Gemfile! Try `rubygems.org` :)